# How to prevent JavaScript from applying the mouseover event several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I noticed a problem when I was testing the `mouseover` event. In the example bellow, there is an image, when you hover it, it gets larger, when mouse is out, it gets back to the normal size, but when you pass the mouse over it many times fast, it keeps getting bigger and smaller several times, like if it had memorized every single pass of the mouse on it and kept playing the animation over and over.

Here is a live example: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bR5cm/1/)
Keep moving the mouse over and out the image fast then take the mouse away and you will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to introduce you to CSS3, the thing that makes jQuery obsolete: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bR5cm/5/)

HTML:

```
<img src="......./Smiley.png" alt="smile" id="imgSmile" />
```

CSS:

```css
#imgSmile {
    width:200px;
    transition:width 0.4s ease;
}
#imgSmile:hover {
    width:250px;
}
```

JS: NONE!

Comment: Looks cleaner, any side effects when using css transitions in place of javascript ? like browser compatibilities ?

Comment: "makes jQuery obsolete" kinda broad statement.

Comment: @TechSupport Browsers that do not support transitions will simply have the image jump to the bigger size. I consider this motivation for users to update their browsers rather than sit around deliberately ignoring the "updates are available" notice.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`.stop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
$(this).stop().animate({width: "200px"}, 'fast');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bR5cm/2/

Comment: So stop() makes the hovered object stop at what ever state it is and apply the animation on it from that point?

Comment: From the docs: When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class while you animate and remove it once the animation is done, and only apply new animation if the class is not applied to the element. Example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#imgSmile').width(200);
       $('#imgSmile').mouseover(function()
       {
           if(!$(this).hasClass('animating')){
              $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
              $(this).addClass('animating');
               $(this).animate({width: "250px"}, 'slow',function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('animating');
               });
           }
       });

    $('#imgSmile').mouseout(function()
      {   
          $(this).animate({width: "200px"}, 'slow');
       });
   });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bR5cm/3/

Comment: This way doesn't give a good solution, try hovering several times, then take the mouse away and try to hover again, the animation won't play, until some time passes.